# What is the meaning of WAL file name?

Tags: postgresql

We know WAL file locate in the **$PGDATA/pg_xlog** directory,  but I don't know the meaning of WAL file ,such as a WAL file which named "0000000A00005283000000E0",

I see some's blog say WAL file name  respect a format name subdivided into 3 sequences of 8 hexa digits defining:

Timeline ID

Block ID

Segment ID

But I still don't understand this. anyone can explain this?

**--query**

```
francs=> select pg_current_xlog_location();
 pg_current_xlog_location 
--------------------------
 5283/D9C2A320
(1 row)

francs=> select pg_xlogfile_name(pg_current_xlog_insert_location());
     pg_xlogfile_name     
--------------------------
 0000000A00005283000000E0
```

Comment: Wha you don't understand in detail?`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

WAL file naming is really an implementation detail. See the source code - starting with the implementation of `pg_xlogfile_name` in `src/backend/access/transam/xlogfuncs.c`, which uses `XLogFileName` in `src/include/access/xlog_internal.h`:

```
#define XLogFileName(fname, tli, logSegNo)  \
    snprintf(fname, MAXFNAMELEN, "%08X%08X%08X", tli,       \
             (uint32) ((logSegNo) / XLogSegmentsPerXLogId), \
             (uint32) ((logSegNo) % XLogSegmentsPerXLogId))
```

From there you can see that *in current PostgreSQL versions* the archive name is eight zero-padded hex digits of timeline ID, then a somewhat oddly formatted value for the segment that works out to the high 32 bits of a 64-bit segment number zero-padded out to 8 hex digits, then the low 32 bits zero padded out to 8 hex digits. That format is really a historical quirk.

You can work that out because of the definition of `XLogSegmentsPerXLogId`:

```
#define XLogSegmentsPerXLogId   (UINT64CONST(0x100000000) / XLOG_SEG_SIZE)
```

which is `1 << 32` i.e. 2^32, so really the `XLogFileName` is just taking the high and low 32 bits.

That said, you shouldn't need to do anything with WAL based on the file names, except use them to uniquely identify a WAL file, so I'm wondering *why* you're asking this. What're you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for replying,  I just want to know the exact meaning of wal filename.

Comment: Does the wal composite of Timeline ID, Block ID, segment ID? I see this from the blog  http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgres-9-3-feature-highlight-pg_xlogdump/

Comment: But can we assume, at least, that the filenames are lexicographically ordered in time?

Comment: The block ID isn't in the WAL file name. Timeline ID and segment number are. I'm not really sure where Michael gets "block ID" - the only usage of "block ID" in the sources refers to heap tables. I think he just means the major half of the segment number.

Comment: Yes, they'll be lexographically ordered, in that the filename is essentially a padded tuple of (timelineid, segid_top_32bits, segid_bottom_32bits). But please use the existing tools for managing WAL, like `pg_archivecleanup`, rather than rolling your own. If the WAL naming scheme changes those tools will get updated; your home rolled one will not.